# function that returns a pointer

Tags: c, function, pointers, scope

I am refreshing my memory of C, and I wanted to test pointers.

I did this simple program, where I call a function that returns a pointer to the largest integer among it's arguments

```
int*function_pointer (int a, int b, int c);

int main ()
{
      printf("Testing pointers\n");// line 1

      int*pointer = pointer_function(10,12,36);
      //pointer_function(10,102,36) is assigned to int*pointer

      printf("Okay, what now...\n");//line 3


      return 0;
}
```

the pointer function

```
int*function_pointer (int a, int b, int c)
{
     int x;
     int*ptr = &x;
     //initially ptr points to the address of x

     if(a > b)
     {
          if(a > c)
          {
               printf("a is the greatest\n);
               ptr = &a;
          }
     }

     if(b > a)
     {
          if(b > c)
          {
              printf("b is the greatest\n");
              ptr = &b;
              //b is 102, so in this scope ptr points to the address of b
          }
     }

     if(c > a)
     {
          if(c > b)
          {
              printf("c is the greatest\n");
              ptr = &c;
          }
      }

      return ptr;
      //function returns the value of ptr which is the address of b
}
```

- at main function `function_pointer(10,102,36)` is called
- inside `function_pointer(...)`, `int a, b, c` are created for that scope
- initially `ptr = &x`
- since `b = 102`, `ptr = &b`
- the functions returns the value of ptr
- at main `pointer = ptr`, hence `pointer = &b`
- but `b` is out of scope, and doesn't have any content
- so how come `*pointer = 102`, shouldn't it return a garbage value since b is not withing the scope of the main function

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can a local variable's memory be accessed outside its scope?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6441218/can-a-local-variables-memory-be-accessed-outside-its-scope)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> but b is out of scope, and doesn't have any content

Your pointer is technically still valid and it just points to memory area. It your case it, when `function_pointer()` returns the `b` still points to memory it was using for local variable (so, in this case on your stack). You **should not** use the memory any longer, but as **memory content your pointer points to** is by default not zeroed when no longer used, then you are simply lucky to still have previous value `102` still there, because as your stack did not expand more than since `function_pointer()` returned as no other code needed to do that.

If you want do to do some tests, you may want to create another function that you call after `function_pointer()`. If that new function you need to  local variables (i. e. array of 150 `int`s). to make your code to use more stack and overwrite leftovers. Then you will no longer see `102`.